# JavaScript changing image source not persisting

Tags: javascript, image

I have to change an image source when the image is clicked. 
The issue is the image changes **only during the execution of the function, but revert to its initial value immediately after!!!**

This is what I have done so far:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cardMouseClick(obj) {
        el = document.getElementById(obj);
        el.src = "image2.jpg";
    alert("Hello!");        
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
   <input type="image" id="b1" src="image1.jpg"  
      onclick="cardMouseClick('b1')"/>

</form>
</body>
```

The image2 is duly displayed while the alert popup Windows awaits for user to click OK.
Then it reverts to image1!

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prevent a page reload:

```
<form id="form1">
   <input type="image" id="b1" src="image1.jpg"  
      onclick="cardMouseClick('b1'); return false;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because its submitting the form. `return` `false` from `cardMouseClick(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              function cardMouseClick(obj) {
                    el = document.getElementById(obj);
                    el.src = "image2.jpg";
                    alert("Hello!");
                    return false;          
                   }
        </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       <form id="form1">
          <input type="image" id="b1" src="image1.jpg"  
            onclick="cardMouseClick('b1')"/>
       </form>
```

Comment: This is weird: Joseph Silber's solution works fine, and your's doesn't! I wionder why?